# Inject vs event in CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am trying to understand the difference of invoking methods in two different beans. The first approach is to inject one bean into the other, then invoke the method of the injected bean in the other bean. The second approach is to use @observe and fire an event. Which one is better?

Comment: i don't know cdi,,but di is a technique , observe should be an observer pattern.. so better it's depend of situation i think..

Comment: DI is at the load and re-init object, it automatically generates the object and invoke the post-init method, while observing is dependent to the context, sometimes an instance of class should be exist in order to invoke the desire method within the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach, injection, is a lot simpler and therefore better. It's also easier to test - there's no event context to set up.

The second approach, event driven, is more complicated, because it introduces a third party (the event framework) to coordinate the two classes. It's harder (takes more code, time and knowledge) to test too.

Use injection: It's widely used, widely supported, widely understood, simpler and easy to test/mock.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've explained, both solutions will do the same thing in this circumstance. An event would be useful if you need more than one thing to observe / listen to the event. Also depends on how you want your application built. Do you want to do the event / listener approach or do it more object oriented?

Comment: A more " conventional " way :p